# 3 parameter Weibull distribution location parameter behaviour

Tags: python, math, weibull

I'm trying to generate a 3 parameter Sigmoid Weibull probability distribution in Python. I want to be able to change the location parameter while keeping everything else constant. I thought this would be quite easy, but I can't figure out why this isn't working. I'm defining my Weibull as:

```
alpha = 1 (location)
beta = 2 (slope)
gamma = 0 (lower asymptote of y-axis)    

y(alpha, beta, gamma) =  1 - (1 - gamma) * exp(-((xx/alpha)**beta))
```

As I vary alpha [.5, 1 , 1.5] I expected to get 3 functions with the same slope, but with different start points. My scale is 0 > 1 on the y.

But I get:

[image: Weibuls a = (.5, 1 , 1.5)]

(lines are alpha [.5, 1 , 1.5] L > R)

To summarise: I want to be able to set the curve location parameter without altering the slope of the function. Can anyone help me out? I'm a little bit new to this sort of thing, so apologies for being naive.

Comment: How do you define a starting point for a function? If you want a delay of the function, you should have another parameter dx. Replace x with x-dx

Answer (score 0):

You can’t. Both location and slope depends on alpha and beta.

You can see this by solving for example for y=0.5, and to differentiate to find the slope.

Stackoverflow cannot show math formulas (Latex), so formulas are given as images.

x value for y=0.5:
[image: x value for y=0.5]

Slope at x=1:
[image: slope at x=1]

EDIT: for completeness, here is the code to show the graphs:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def f(a,b,g,x):
   return  1 - (1 - g) * np.exp(-((x/a)**b)) 

x = np.linspace(0, 3, 100)
plt.figure(figsize=[4,3])
for a in [0.5,1,1.5]:
   y = f(a,2,0,x)
   plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Okay, I see your point. The function as defined means alpha manipulates slope and location. I was wondering if there is some clear error in the definition of my function that would allow the behaviour shown here when fixed:

https://www.weibull.com/hotwire/issue15/relbasics15.htm

Is the best way to replicate this just to bump up or down all of my x values after generating the base function? Like the delay you suggested.

P.S thanks for supplying the plotting code  -I'll do that in future.